# Java Random Utility Generating Too Many 0's And Static Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, random, zero

The line `birthdays[j] = rnd.nextInt(365);` seems to generate extra 0's in the `int[] birthdays` array.  It also seems to add an EXTRA 0 into the array and generate static values depending on how many simulations I run and how many birthdays I generate. For instance, if I do 5 simulations and enter a 3 for the number of people in each simulation's "birthday pool" I always get an array of `[0, 0, 289, 362]`.

Any help understanding the problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the birthday problem Simulator\n");
        String userAnswer="";
        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            int [] userInput = promptAndRead(stdIn);
            double probability = compute(userInput[0], userInput[1]);

            // Print results
            System.out.println("For a group of " + userInput[1] + " people, the probability");
            System.out.print("that two people have the same birthday is\n");
            System.out.println(probability);

            System.out.print("\nDo you want to run another set of simulations(y/n)? :");

            //eat or skip empty line
            stdIn.nextLine();
            userAnswer = stdIn.nextLine();


        } while (userAnswer.equals("y"));

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        stdIn.close();
    }

    // Prompt user to provide the number of simulations and number of people and return them as an array
    public static int[] promptAndRead(Scanner stdIn) {

        int numberOfSimulations = 0;
        while(numberOfSimulations < 1 || numberOfSimulations > 50000) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter the number of simulations to do. (1 - 50000) ");
            numberOfSimulations = stdIn.nextInt();
        }

        int sizeOfGroup = 0;
        while(sizeOfGroup < 2 || sizeOfGroup > 365) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter the size of the group of people. (2 - 365) ");
            sizeOfGroup = stdIn.nextInt();
        }

        int[] simulationVariables = {numberOfSimulations, sizeOfGroup};
        return simulationVariables;
    }


    // This is the method that actually does the calculations.
    public static double compute(int numOfSims, int numOfPeeps) {

        double numberOfSims = 0.0;
        double simsWithCollisions = 0.0;
        int matchingBirthdays = 0;
        int[] birthdays = new int[numOfPeeps + 1];
        int randomSeed = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfSims; i++)
        {   
            randomSeed++;
            Random rnd = new Random(randomSeed);
            birthdays = new int[numOfPeeps + 1];
            matchingBirthdays = 0;

            for(int j = 0; j < numOfPeeps; j++) {
                birthdays[j] = rnd.nextInt(365);
                Arrays.sort(birthdays);
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < numOfPeeps; k++) {
                if(birthdays[k] == birthdays[k+1]) {
                    matchingBirthdays++;
                }
            }

            if(matchingBirthdays > 0) {
                simsWithCollisions = simsWithCollisions + 1;
            }
        }
        numberOfSims = numOfSims;
        double chance = (simsWithCollisions / numberOfSims);
        return chance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The line "birthdays[j] = rnd.nextInt(365);" seems to generate extra 0's in the int[] birthdays array.

Well, it doesn't.  The array elements where zero to start with.

What that statement actually does is to generate a single random number (from 0 to 364) and assign it to *one* element of the array; i.e. the jth element.   That is not what is required for your problem.

Now, we could fix your code for you, but that defeats the purpose of your homework.  Instead I will give you a HINT:

- The `birthdays` array is supposed to contain a COUNT of the number of people with a birthday on each day of the year.  You have to COUNT them.  One at a time.

Think about it ...

Comment: Yes, I'm repeating that statement that generate multiple random numbers, placing them into the array via a loop.  I've done a little more toying around and now notice I get half of my array back as 0's.  So if there are 10 values in the array, I get 5 of them are 0's.

Comment: Well "toying around" is not the right way to develop programs.  Start stop "toying around"  and start *thinking* about what your code is doing and what it needs to do.

Comment: @StephenC I applaud your directness, alas I can only give you one upvote!

Answer (score 1):

`int` arrays are by default initialized to 0 unless explicitly specified. Please see this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) about Arrays.

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem myself.  The issue was that having the "Arrays.sort(birthdays);" statement inside of a loop.  That generated extra 0's.

Comment: It did not "generate" the zeros.  It moved them around!  And then you ended up replacing non-zero elements with other non-zero elements.